# Select content from multiple tables and display

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following tables : Question , Answer , User_Answers

Im trying to get a query where I can print out the question , the answers and the answer that the user chose.

So far Iv managed to print out the question with a user answer , but nothing is in order.

Tables with sample data:

```
**Question Table**

id    Test_ID    QText
--------------------------------------------
1       1       What colour is the sky? 


**Answer Table** 

id    Question_ID   AText
-------------------------------
1       1          Green
2       1          Blue
3       1          Red
4       1          Yellow


**User_Answers Table**

id    User_ID    Question_ID    Answer_ID
---------------------------------------------------
1      1            1             2

**Correct_Answers Table**

id    Question_ID    Answer_ID
---------------------------------------------------
1          1            1             

Expected Outcome :

Question xxxxxxx



Answer    Your Answer    Correct Answer
------------------------------------------
  1                              x 
  2          x                 
  3          
  4
```

Comment: `ORDER BY q.id` at the end of your SQL will get the results in order.

Comment: @JNevill Nope , that didnt do it

Comment: Since there can be many questions are you going to filter by question id? Or this query is supposed to return only questions where user chose an answer? So questions he did not answer are not needed?

Comment: @IvanStarostin The user answer table contains only questions that have been answered by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    q.QText, q.id AS QId, ua.id, qa.AText,
    case when qa.ID = ua.Answer_ID then 'x' else NULL end as IsUserAnswer
FROM user_answers ua
INNER JOIN question q ON q.ID = ua.Question_ID
INNER JOIN answer qa ON qa.Question_ID = q.ID
WHERE ua.User_ID=1
ORDER BY QId, qa.ID
```

u missed join from `questions` to `answers` by `question_id`

Comment: I have it working , except that the questions are out of order . When it prints in php , it shows the first question , then the next and then the answers for the first . Its always one question ahead.

Comment: Try to execute the query in phpmyadmin. It seems to work fine. Scenario you are describing looks like an issue with `$lastQuestionID` variable. Another possible reason: ensure you are sorting by `qa.ID`, not by `ua.ID`. Probably it is better also to change `ua.ID` to `qa.ID` in selected columns list.

Comment: the query works . Its just the php . I need it to only print the question once

Comment: don't you miss curved brackets after `if`?

Comment: I dont think i need them . I added them in and it didnt make a difference

Comment: In php code there is a line before the last one with a single quote and semicolon. This looks incorrect. Are you collecting there answer list into a variable?

Comment: Note you are ordering by `useranswer.id` instead of `answer.id` just as I mentioned couple of comments above.

Comment: It doesnt make a difference.

Comment: Your `table` tag structure is broken. Every new 'qID' you are starting a new table without closing previous one.

Comment: That might be it , ill see if i can fix it

Comment: Iv just looked at the code and the table is being closed

Comment: yes, after the whole `while` finishes. check out raw html.

Comment: I have , It prints the question then the start of the table and then the answers before closing the table and doing it again . However when it prints the first question , it also prints the second question before printing the first answers

Comment: This can not be accomplished with PHP code you provided. Do not "inspect elements", review "page source".